# Are Kahler differentials the same on the affine closure on a quasi-affine scheme?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, kahler-differentials

Let $X$ be a quasi-affine scheme; that is, the natural map 
$$X\rightarrow \overline{X}:=Spec(\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X))$$
 is an inclusion.  Each scheme has a quasi-coherent sheaf of Kahler differentials $\Omega$, and the above open inclusion induces a $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$-module map of global Kahler differentials

$$ \Gamma(\Omega_{\overline{X}})\rightarrow \Gamma(\Omega_{X})$$

Is this map always an isomorphism?

**Edit:** Changed $\mathcal{O}_X$ to $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$.

Comment: You mean $Spec(\Gamma(\mathcal O_X))$ ? Otherwise the spec of the sheaf is just $X$... 

Comment: Yes, corrected.

Comment: What is the meaning of "inclusion" in this context? (I'm not claiming the usage is not standard, only that I am not familiar with it.)

Comment: Its an *open* inclusion, so it induces an isomorphism of schemes onto an open subscheme.

Answer (score 7):

The assumption implies that the natural embedding induces an isomorphism $\Gamma(X,\mathscr O_X)\simeq \Gamma(\overline X,\mathscr O_{\overline X})$. Then this means that  the complement of $X$ has at least codimension $2$.

In addition assume that $X$ is noetherian and $S_2$ (for instance normal).

In this case *if* $\Omega_{\overline X}$ is a reflexive sheaf, then the restriction 
$\Gamma(\overline X,\Omega_{\overline X})\to \Gamma(X,\Omega_{\overline X})=\Gamma(X,\Omega_{X})$ is an isomorphism.

More generally, let $Z:=\overline X\setminus X$. If $\mathrm{depth}_Z\Omega_{\overline X}\geq 2$ then the restriction $\Gamma(\overline X,\Omega_{\overline X})\to \Gamma(X,\Omega_{X})$ is an isomorphism.
This certainly holds if $\Omega_{\overline X}$ is a reflexive sheaf, but obviously it could hold "by accident" even if one of the above conditions fail, so I am not claiming that these are necessary conditions, but at least they sure seem to provide a natural set of conditions under which the required map is an isomorphism.

**Sketch** that if $X$ is $S_2$, then a *reflexive* coherent sheaf $\mathscr F$ is also $S_2$:
First observe that by the argument in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45347/why-does-the-s2-property-of-a-ring-correspond-to-the-hartogs-phenomenon/45616#45616) to another MO question we may assume that $X$ is affine and it is enough to prove that $H^i_x(X,\mathscr F)=0$ for $i=0,1$ for all $x\in X$ and it also follows that $\mathrm{depth}_Z\mathscr F\geq 2$ even if $Z$ is not contained in an affine piece of $X$. To do that write $\mathscr F^\vee$ as the quotient of a (locally) free sheaf ($X$ is affine!). Then $\mathscr F$ is a submodule of the dual of this locally free sheaf, let's call it $\mathscr E$, and the quotient $\mathscr E/\mathscr F$ is torsion-free. Therefore none of them have torsion and so $H^0_x(X,\mathscr F)=0$ and $H^1_x(X,\mathscr F)$ embeds into $H^1_x(X,\mathscr E)$. But the latter is $0$ by the assumption that $X$ is $S_2$.

**EDIT 1** removed intro paragraph about the starting assumption.

**EDIT 2** added "more generally" paragraph.

**EDIT 3** added noetherian assumption. this is probably not necessary but without this one should possibly be more careful about the other conditions.

**EDIT 4** Added **Sketch** above.

Comment: Yes, Sandor, you are correct in that I explicitly want $\overline{X}=Spec(\mathcal{O}_X)$.  And its true that, if we know $\Omega_{\overline{X}}$ is reflexive, then we are done.

Comment: On the other hand, it is almost equivalent to being reflexive.

Comment: To work correctly with the depth, do you have to assume $\overline{X}$ is noetherian ? 

Comment: @Qing Liu: I suppose I secretly assumed it was noetherian. 

Comment: Sandor, on an S2 scheme, is it true that every reflexive sheaf is S2?  I thought you needed S2 + G1 (do you know a reference?)

Comment: Karl, I think for the direction *reflexive* $\Rightarrow$ $S_2$ you don't need $G_1$. You need that for the converse. See a sketch above why. (And let me know if there is something wrong with it).

Comment: Heres a potential difficulty.  Even if you can find an $\overline{X}$ with non-reflexive Kahler differentials, and an open subscheme $X$ whose complement is codim $\geq2$, it still is guaranteed that $\overline{X}=Spec(\Gamma(\mathcal{O}_X))$.  For example, if the appropriate singular point is the intersection of two components, the affine closure of $X$ won't be $\overline{X}$, no matter how small the complement is.