# Is a terminal symplectic variety S_4?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, holomorphic-symplectic

For purposes of this question "terminal symplectic variety" means a normal variety which is symplectic (in the usual sense of symplectic singularities) and whose singular locus has codimension $\geq 4$ (the equivalence of this with the usual definition of terminal is a theorem of Namikawa).

Symplectic varieties has lots of nice properties; For example, they are always Cohen-Macaulay, which is a condition about niceness with respect to depth.  So, one can hope for others.

> Is a terminal symplectic variety necessarily $S_4$?

I should warn any potential answerers that my understanding of the $S_4$ property is very poor (it's an exceptionally tough thing to Google, since it's not even the dominant use of that term in mathematics). I hesitate to even give a definition for fear of messing it up;  I believe it means that every ideal sheaf of codimension $\leq 3$ has depth equal to its codimension.

Comment: The condition Cohen-Macaulay is equivalent to $\text{S}_n$ holding for every integer $n > 0$.  

Comment: Maybe I should ellaborate on my comment.  A ring $R$ is $S_n$ if the depth of every local ring $R_{\mathfrak p}$ is at least $\text{min}(\dim R_{\mathfrak p}, n)$.  Cohen-Macaulay means that the depth at every local ring equals the dimension of that local ring.

Comment: @Karl: That looks like it should be an answer and not just a comment.

Comment: The definition of $S_n$ for sheaves is discussed here, in case someone wants to see the definition(s): http://mathoverflow.net/questions/22228/what-is-serres-condition-s-n-for-sheaves

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ben,

a terminal singularity is Cohen-Macaulay and Cohen-Macaulay implies $S_n$ for all $n$.

By the way, I already mentioned this in my [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63257/do-some-of-the-local-cohomology-groups-of-the-structure-sheaf-on-the-singular-loc/63261#63261) to your previous question about this issue. ([here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63257/do-some-of-the-local-cohomology-groups-of-the-structure-sheaf-on-the-singular-loc/63261#63261)).

Comment: You're right; I was being silly and somehow missed that.  Thanks for the (many) answers.

Comment: No worries. Cheers. :)


Answer (score 6):

I'm posting this as an answer due to encouragement to do so from Noah Snyder in the comments.

As mentioned above in my comment.  A ring $R$ is ${\text{S}}_n$ if for every prime ideal $\mathfrak{q} \subseteq R$, $R_q$ has depth at least $\text{min}(\dim R_{\mathfrak q}, n)$.

A ring is Cohen-Macaulay if the depth of each $R_{\mathfrak{q}}$ is equal to $\dim R_{\mathfrak q}$.  Thus a ring is Cohen-Macaulay if and only if it is $\text{S}_n$ for every $n$.  In particular, any terminal, or even log terminal singularity is Cohen-Macaulay and thus also $\text{S}_4$.

Log canonical singularities don't satisfy this property (they need to be Cohen-Macaulay).  However, if you have a family of varieties with log canonical singularities say over a smooth curve, the $\text{S}_n$ property is is closed (in particular, a limit of $\text{S}_n$ varieties is $\text{S}_n$).  See the paper of Kollar-Kovacs, [HERE](https://arxiv.org/abs/0902.0648)

Comment: Thanks to you too for your many answers.  Hopefully I can stop being stupid about algebraic geometry soon.