# Restriction of sheaf

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves

Suppose $X$ is a smooth variety and $F$ is a locally free sheaf on $X$. Let $U$ be an open subset of $X$ and $i$ denote the inclusion map.
Is $i_*i^*F$ equal to $F$?

Answer (score 7):

No. For example, let $X = P^1$, $U = A^1$ and $F = O_X$. Then $i^*F = O_U$ and the global sections of $i^*F$ is the algebra of polynomials $k[t]$. Therefore $\Gamma(X,i_*i^*F) = \Gamma(U,i^*F) = k[t]$, while $\Gamma(X,F) = k$.

Answer (score 4):

This is true if and only if the complement of $U$ has codimension at least $2$.
To see that this condition is sufficient see [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45347/why-does-the-s2-property-of-a-ring-correspond-to-the-hartogs-phenomenon/45354#45354).
To see that it is necessary, see Sasha's [example](https://mathoverflow.net/a/114039), or take any $X$ and any Cartier divisor $D$ on $X$ and note that for $U=X\setminus \operatorname{Supp}D$, $i^*\mathscr O_X(mD)\simeq \mathscr O_U\simeq i^*\mathscr O_X(nD)$ for any $m,n\in \mathbb Z$, so $i_*i^*F$ can't be $F$ for both choices.

*Remark* for the codimension $2$ condition, you don't actually need smoothness. See the linked answer for more.

Comment: @LSpice: you are right! Thanks for the correction. :)

Answer (score 1):

In general, we have the socalled projection formula: if $f:X\to Y$ is a morphism of ringed spaces, $\mathcal F$ an $\mathcal O_X$-module, and $E$ be a locally-free $\mathcal O_Y$ module of finite rank, then $f_* (\mathcal F \otimes f^{*} E) \simeq f_{*}\mathcal F \otimes E$.

Edit (following Will's [remark](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/114032/restriction-of-sheaf#comment292160_114035)): The projection formula yields in the case of an open immersion $i:U \subset X$ the following identity : $i_* i^* F \simeq i_*\mathcal O_U \otimes F$. Therefore, if $U$ has codimension at least 2 in $X$, then $i_* i^* F\simeq F$ by normality of $X$.

Comment: You need the assumption $f_* \mathcal O_U=\mathcal O_X$, which is not satisfied for all open immersions.

Comment: Thanks, you are perfectly right! (I had in mind a morphism with connected fibers) So here here one can just say that $i_*i^*F= i_* \mathcal O_X \otimes F$.

Comment: In particular, as $X$ is smooth hence normal, the desired property holds as soon as $U$ has codimension at least $2$.