# A question from GTM 52 of Hartshone

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

This question was appeared somewhere in MS(not posted by me), however the technique used there was of scheme theory, so I decided to post it again here.

That is the exercise 3.20 on page 23 of GTM 52 by Hartshone.

> Let $Y$ be a variety of dimension $\ge 2$, $P$ is a normal point on $Y$, $f$ is a regular function on $Y\setminus P$. Prove that $f$ extends to a regular function on $Y$ and this is failed for dimension 1.

I have got no idea using the information in section 3, chapter 1 in that book to solve this problem. Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: check this in the local ring of $P$... ;)

Comment: maybe using thm 11.5 from Matsumura, Commutative Ring Theory...

Comment: See this MO question and the answers given to it: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/45347/why-does-the-s2-property-of-a-ring-correspond-to-the-hartogs-phenomenon/45354#45354

Comment: The point is that the local ring has depth at least 2. If you don't know what depth is, you need to learn it.

Comment: So, there is no solution (using the knowledge of section 3) for this problem ?

Comment: If you combine MBeasy and Matthieu's comments you get a "section 3" solution. The ideas needed are in the proof of Theorem 3.2 plus one tiny extra piece of commutative algebra about normal Noetherian domains.

Comment: What I get from these two comment are : $\mathcal{O}_{P}$ is Noetherian normal, then it is equal to $\bigcap_{\text{ht}\mathfrak{q}=1}\mathcal{O}_{P}_{\mathfrak{q}}$. So what more can I get from this ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a "$\sim$ section 3" solution:

- By [Matsumura, 11.5] $\mathscr O_P=\bigcap_{\mathfrak p\in \mathrm{Spec}\mathscr O_P, \mathrm{ht}\mathfrak p=1} (\mathscr O_P)_{\mathfrak p}$
- The conditions imply that $f\in (\mathscr O_P)_{\mathfrak p}$ for every $\mathfrak p\in \mathrm{Spec}\mathscr O_P, \mathrm{ht}\\,\mathfrak p=1$ and hence it is in the RHS of the above equality.

This implies what you want. I assume that you can come up with a $1$-dimensional counter-example.

---

So, this is a "section 3" solution, but only if you accept using commutative algebra theorems from elsewhere. Of course, you have to, because it is impossible to go through [Hartshorne] without that. However, once you make that allowance, then you should be open to more.

[Matsumura, 11.5] is actually [Hartshorne, II.6.3A], so strictly speaking not "section 3 (Chapter I)". On the other hand, if you are dealing with *normal* varieties, then it is essential that you know Serre's criterion, that is, [Hartshorne, II.8.22A] or [Matsumura, 23.8], which says that normal is equivalent to $S_2$ and $R_1$.

The $S_2$ condition is essentially saying that the statement of the exercise holds. For more on this see this [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45347/why-does-the-s2-property-of-a-ring-correspond-to-the-hartogs-phenomenon/45354#45354) and the answers there.