# Zero-cohomology of birational varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology

Let $f:X\dashrightarrow Y$ be a birational map of smooth projective varieties, i.e., there exist open subsets $U_1, \subset X$ and $U_2 \subset Y$ such that $f|_{U_1} : U_1 \rightarrow U_2$ is an isomorphism.

There is an homomorphism induced by $f$ given by

$$ f_* : Div(X) \rightarrow Div(Y) ,  D\mapsto \overline{ f(D|_{U_1}) }$$
Is known that if $f$ is a small modification then $h^0(f_*(D))=h^0(D)$ for any divisor $D$ of X.

Exists a relation between $h^0(D)$ and  $h^0(f_*(D))$ in general for a divisor $D$ of X?

If $D$ is a divisor of $X$ and $\mathcal{L}_D$ is the associated line bundle we consider the following notation $h^0(D) = h^0(X, \mathcal{L}_D)$.

Comment: This is a weird question. How do you define $f_*$ without knowing the answer to this?

Comment: Let me ask for clarification: is $f$ a _morphism_ or just a _map_?

Comment: $f$ is a birational map, not necessarily a morphism.
$f_*$ is the push-forwards homomorphism.

Comment: @Joaquin: this is still a total mess. You should assume that $Y$ is at least $S_2$ and explain what you mean by $f_*$ if $f$ is not necessarily a morphism. Supposedly you want the strict transform of the divisor, but we shouldn't be **guessing** what you are asking. Also, $h^0(D)$ makes no sense if $D$ is a divisor and not a sheaf. Finally, $\mathrm{Pic} X$ is a set/group of **sheaves** not divisors: $D\in\mathrm{Pic} X$ is still a *sheaf* and *not a divisor* even if you *call* it a divisor. If you want help, at least invest enough energy to put the question together in a semi-intelligent way.

Comment: Dear Joaquin, let me add a bit to Sándor's suggestions above. It might be a good idea to describe the situation you're interested in, in more detail. For example, you write "any divisor D in Pic(X)", which suggests that maybe you only want to consider _smooth_  varieties X and Y. (Of course I might be wrong about that.) Even if the question admits an answer in greater generality, it is often better to start off in this more specific setting, to avoid confusions of the kind that arose.

Another tip is to be very careful when using notation that has multiple meanings: you used...


Comment: the solid arrow $\rightarrow$ to denote a rational map, but often that symbol is reserved for morphisms, and a broken arrow $\dashrightarrow$ is used for rational maps. As a result, it was easy to think that $f$ in your question was supposed to be a morphism. (Likewise, the notation $f_∗$ can be ambiguous, as Sándor pointed out.) Anyway, these are just some ideas about what would have made the question easier to understand for me. Best wishes, Artie.

Comment: Thanks for the sugesstions Artie and Sándor.
I edited some of the mistakes.

Comment: OK, so this is much better. Of course, now the answer you accepted does not answer your question. Which makes me wonder what you had in mind when you accepted it. Sasha did not know what you really asked so he answered what he assumed you did, but you should have realized that. I'm sorry to be so critical, but I feel that if we invest time and energy to answer questions, it is a reasonable expectation that the person asking the question would do the same. 

Comment: As you define it, $f_*$ depends on the choice of $U_1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the latest formulation is much better, but there are still some problems with this setup. You can push-forward cycles via morphisms, but rational maps are trickier.

First of all if the inverse of $f$ contracts a divisor, then $f_*$ does not (necessarily) respect linear equivalence. Here is an example. Let $X$ be your favorite smooth projective variety and $\pi:Y\to X$ the blow-up of a (closed) point $x\in X$. Let $f:X\dashrightarrow Y$ be the inverse of $\pi$ (as a rational map). Now let $\mathfrak d$ be a very ample linear system on $X$. If $D\in\mathfrak d$ is such that $x\not\in X$, then $f_*D\sim\pi^*D$ and if  $D'\in\mathfrak d$ is such that $x\in D'$ and, for simplicity, the multiplicity of $D'$ at $x$ is $1$ (this happens for instance if $X=\mathbb P^n$ and $\mathfrak d$ is the hyperplane class), then $f_*D'=\pi^*D'-E \sim \pi^*D-E\sim f_*D-E$.

Therefore there is a short exact sequence of sheaves on $Y$:
$$
0\to \mathscr O_Y(f_*D')\to \mathscr O_Y(f_*D) \to \mathscr O_E \to 0.
$$
Taking global sections one obtains another short exact sequence:
$$
0\to H^0(Y,\mathscr O_Y(f_*D'))\to H^0(Y,\mathscr O_Y(f_*D)) \to H^0(E,\mathscr O_E) \to 0.
$$
Here the non-obvious exactness follows from the fact that $f_*D\cap E=\emptyset$ and hence the restriction of the corresponding section to $E$ is a non-zero global section of $\mathscr O_E$.

This shows that (using the OP's notation): 
$$
h^0(f_*D')= h^0(f_*D)-1.
$$
On the other hand, from the projection formula it follows that
$$
h^0(D)=h^0(f_*D)
$$
and hence
$$
h^0(D')=h^0(f_*D')+1
$$

---

OK, so we see that we better assume that the inverse of $f$ does not contract divisors. I assume you meant this to be part of the assumption that $f$ is a *small modification*, but you also seemed to be asking without that. Also, the above should warn you that using notation like $h^0(f_*D)$ is dangerous. The usage of $h^0$ suggests using the linear equivalence *class* of $D$, but $f_*D$ is not well-defined for that. Of course, this can still be done right, you just have to make sure to emphasize that $D$ is an explicit divisor, not a divisor class. (So for instance this is another reason why your original $D\in\mathrm{Pic}\\, X$ was bad).

Assuming that $f^{-1}$ does not contract divisors, there is of course a problem if $f$ contracts a divisor. Just take $D''=f_*D'$ from the above example. Clearly, $\pi_*D''=D'$ and we already saw that 
$$
h^0(D'')=h^0(\pi_*D'')-1.
$$

---

So, we're left with the case when neither $f$ nor $f^{-1}$ contract any divisors. In this case
it is indeed true what you want. Here is why:

The assumption means that in this case we have open sets $U\subseteq X$ and $V\subseteq Y$ such that  $\mathrm{codim}_X(X\setminus U)\geq 2$, $\mathrm{codim}_Y(Y\setminus V)\geq 2$, and $f:U\to V$ is an isomorphism. In this case clearly we have that 
$$
H^0(X,\mathscr O_X(D)) = H^0(U,\mathscr O_U(D|_U)) = H^0(V,\mathscr O_V(f(D|_U))) = H^0(Y,\mathscr O_Y(f_*D)).
$$
The middle equality is obvious the other two follows from the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are $S_2$. This is sometimes called the Hartog property. See [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45347/why-does-the-s2-property-of-a-ring-correspond-to-the-hartogs-phenomenon/45354#45354) for more.

---

Note that this does not need $X$ and $Y$ to be smooth, only $S_2$. In order to deal with divisors you're probably better off assuming that they are normal. For some musings about that see [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35736/the-canonical-line-bundle-of-a-normal-variety/46663#46663).

Also, to be fair, you asked for a relation in general, not equality so I assume you are aware of some of the above. I think that in general the relationship between $h^0(D)$ and $h^0(f_*D)$ will be very complicated and has to do with how $D$ relates to the exceptional divisor(s).

Answer (score 2):

For any birational map $f:X \to Y$ the projection formula gives $h^0(X,f^*L) = h^0(Y,L)$ for any line bundle $L$ on $Y$. If the morphism is small then the map $f^*:Pic(Y) \to Pic(X)$ is an isomorphism, so for any $L' \in Pic(X)$ there is $L \in Pic(Y)$ such that $L' = f^*(L)$. Consequently $h^0(X,L') = h^0(Y,L)$. It remains to note that $f_*(L') = f_*(f^*(L)) = L$.

Comment: This seems way too complicated. You don't need anything else but the definition of $f_*$....

Comment: The projection formula does not give what you say in the first line. It only gives $h^0(X,f^*L)=h^0(Y,L\otimes f_*\mathcal{O}_X$. So, for example if $X$ is the normalizatiion of a non-normal $Y$, we do not get what you say. Of course this is irrelevant in the `small' case above.

Comment: @Mohan: why is it irrelevant in the small case? If $Y$ is regular in codimension 2, but not normal, then $H^0(X,f^*\mathscr O_Y)\neq H^0(Y,\mathscr O_Y)$.

Comment: @Mohan: Yes, I assumed implicitly that $Y$ is normal. On the other hand, note that the higher direct images of the structure sheaf (which may be nonzero if the singularity of $Y$ is not rational) do not change the global sections.

Answer (score 0):

[**EDIT**] In view of the latest edit to the question this is no longer an answer. However, I will not delete it as I think it contributed to the revision of the question, so it should be part of the record.

---

If $D\in\mathrm{Pic}\\, X$, in fact if $D$ is **any sheaf** on $X$ and $f:X\to Y$ is a continuous map, then for any $V\subseteq Y$ open $H^0(V,f_*D):=H^0(f^{-1}V,D)$ by definition, so in particular $H^0(Y,f_*D):=H^0(X,D)$ and you don't need any of the assumptions.

Comment: The problem is that a priori the pushforward of a line bundle is not a  line bundle. In other words, the pushforward of sheaves is not the same as the pushforward of divisors. 

Comment: That's what I thought first as the reasonable interpretation, but even though the OP used "$D$", he never said it was a divisor. The only stated property is that $D\in\mathrm{Pic} X$, which says it is a sheaf. Just because the OP uses a letter that's **usually** means divisors, it does not make it one. At best this is a very sloppy question.

Comment: p.s.: By the way, if $D$ were a divisor, then WTH is $h^0(D)$?

Comment: p.p.s.: In fact, how do you define the notion of a divisor under the assumptions?

Comment: Undoubtedly, the question is very sloppy. But it seems that I was correct in guessing what the question was.

Comment: $D$ is a divisor, sorry for the confusion, i will edit it.