# When is the dualizing sheaf globally generated?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, birational-geometry

Let $X$ be a projective integral Cohen-Macaulay variety (over $\mathbb{C}$, if that makes things easier). The Cohen-Macaulay condition says that the dualizing complex (see [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/46663/65875)) is concentrated in degree $-\dim X$, and so we define the dualizing sheaf to be this cohomology sheaf.

> My question is simple: are there any situations where this dualizing
> sheaf is known to be globally generated?

For smooth or Gorenstein curves of arithmetic genus at least one, this is true, but I am specifically interested when the dualizing sheaf is not invertible (such as Cohen-Macaulay curves or suitable surfaces).

Thanks in advance.